# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am very new to coding and I am trying to make a "bad bank" app for my bootcamp. I have run into this error trying to use the new render method as the one in the professor's video was outdated. I believe this error is actually causing the navbar to not show in my react app also. Any help is much appreciated.

The error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
at Object.useRef (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:50918:25)
at HashRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:47317:55)
at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:22502:22)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:25788:17)
at beginWork (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:27084:20)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:12094:18)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:12138:20)
at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:12195:35)
at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:32069:11)

at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:31316:16)
```

My code- index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import{CreateAccount} from './createaccount.js';
import{Home} from './home.js';
import{Login} from './login.js';
import{Withdraw} from './withdraw.js';
import{Balance} from './balance.js';
import{AllData} from './alldata.js';
import{Deposit} from './deposit.js';
import {StrictMode} from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import{NavBar} from './navbar.js'


const UserContext = React.createContext(null);

const rootElement = 
document.getElementById('root');
const root = 
createRoot(rootElement);

function Spa() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      
      <NavBar/>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{users:[{name:'abel',email:'abel@mit.edu',password:'secret',balance:100}]}}>
        <div className="container" style={{padding: "20px"}}>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/CreateAccount/" component={CreateAccount} />
          <Route path="/login/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/deposit/" component={Deposit} />
          <Route path="/withdraw/" component={Withdraw} />
          <Route path="/balance/" component={Balance} />
          <Route path="/alldata/" component={AllData} />
        </div>
      </UserContext.Provider>      
    </HashRouter>

  );
};

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Spa />
  </StrictMode>,
);
```

Comment: Share the code where you used `useRef` hook.

Comment: that's what's confusing because I'm not using useRef

Comment: How is that possible, could you share your codebase repo.

Comment: I just uploaded it as https://github.com/bridget2270/badbankapp I'm not surre how its possible it could also be that because I used starter code I can't find the useRef

Answer (score 0):

I think the value that you're passing to the component should actually be an element.

```
<Route path="/" exact component={<Home/>} />
<Route path="/CreateAccount/" component={<CreateAccount/>} />
<Route path="/login/" component={<Login/>} />
<Route path="/deposit/" component={<Deposit/>} />
<Route path="/withdraw/" component={<Withdraw/>} />
<Route path="/balance/" component={<Balance/>} />
<Route path="/alldata/" component={<AllData/>} />
```

Can you change this and see if it works?

[Official Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main)

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately still getting the same error